# Problem using regex to extract text

Tags: regex, xor

I need to extract from the following lines of code

```
<label for="<%=foobar.bar %>">Password:</label>

<label for="foobar">Password:</label>
```

I need to extract `foobar`, I can use this: `(?<=for=")[^"]+(?=("))` to extract:

```
<%=foobar.bar %>
```

and

```
foobar
```

but I don't want `<%=` or `.bar` and if I try to create `(?<=for=")[^"]+(?=(")) | (?<=for="<%=)[^"]+(?=("))` it doesn't work becuase the label that included `<%=` meets both conditions and I don't think you can use XOR? Is this anything anyone can help me with?

Merci :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it's better to not create uber-regexes. Do your task in several steps:

1. Extract `<%=foobar.bar %>` or `foobar` with your regex `(?<=for=")[^"]+(?=("))`
2. Check if result matches regex like `<%=([\w]+)\.bar\s*%>`.
3. If it does use `$1` group from match, otherwise use result of step 2.
4. You get foobar

Comment: thank you, I used (?<=for=\")[^\"]+(?=(\")) and then went on to use: (?<=<%=\s*)[^\s]+(?=\.bar\s*%>)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(?<for="(<%=)?)[^" ]*(?=( %>)?")
```

Assuming that what you want to capture never includes spaces.  Otherwise you can try:

```
(?<for="(<%=)?)[^"]*?(?=( %>)?")
```

To use a non greedy form of `[^"]*`